# Turing-Complete Supervised Learning Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, turing-completeness

I'm trying to decide on what algorithm I should use for my machine learning project. I need Turing-completeness. What supervised learning algorithms are Turing-complete? Of those, what are the best?

Thanks

Comment: Learning algorithms usually work only for constant-sized input. Such algorithms aren't eligible to be Turing-complete. What are you really after?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm building a system that simulates objects, and I'll build those rules of simulation using a machine learning algorithm. I figured that it must be Turing-complete... is that not true?